How do you type a subset of arrays to ensure between them they contain all values of a full set?
If I have a full set of known values:
const fullSet = [1, 2, 3, 4] as const

type FullSet = (typeof fullSet)[number] // type FullSet = 1 | 3 | 2 | 4

I want 3 subsets which between themselves contain all values within the full set.
For example, I tried:
type S<S1, S2> = Readonly<Array<Exclude<FullSet, S1 | S2>>>

const subset1: S<Subset2, Subset3> = [1] as const
type Subset1 = (typeof subset1)[number]

const subset2: S<Subset1, Subset3> = [2, 3] as const
type Subset2 = (typeof subset2)[number]

const subset3: S<Subset1, Subset2> = [4] as const
type Subset3 = (typeof subset3)[number]

But this naturally leads to circular dependencies, namely (for example):

'subset1' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
Type alias 'Subset1' circularly references itself.

I am after something which, when adding a new value to the full set, type-errors that the new value is not included in 1 (and only 1) of the 3 subsets.

There are lots of approaches. If you want to keep your basic approach then you must break the circularity and check afterward, possibly like this playground link. If you want to refactor then there are so many ways to do it... maybe like this playground link. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz sorry, both those links are not working for me. Typscript is just loading indefinitely. Edit: don't worry, works now, must have been a chrome issue. yeah both those work, was looking more for a solution along the lines of the first though

There are lots of possible approaches to something like this. If you want to keep your code as close to the current version as you can, then you simply must break the circularity by first assigning the values to variables, and giving a name to their types, and then doing the checking as a separate step.  For example:
type Check<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = void;

const subset1 = [1] as const
type Subset1 = (typeof subset1)[number]
type CheckSubset1 = Check<readonly Subset1[], S<Subset2, Subset3>>

const subset2 = [2, 3] as const
type Subset2 = (typeof subset2)[number]
type CheckSubset2 = Check<readonly Subset2[], S<Subset1, Subset3>>

const subset3 = [4] as const
type Subset3 = (typeof subset3)[number]
type CheckSubset3 = Check<readonly Subset3[], S<Subset1, Subset2>>

The Check<T, U> utility type doesn't really return anything useful, but it will complain if you call Check<T, U> with a T and U that don't mutually extend each other. It's sort of an equality check.  So CheckSubset1's line only compiles if readonly Subset1[] and S<Subset2, Subset3> are assignable to each other.  Same with the CheckSubset2 and CheckSubset3 lines. If you add or remove members on fullSet you'll get errors in the appropriate places, telling you what the problem is:
const fullSet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10] as const // added 10 here

type CheckSubset1 = Check<readonly Subset1[], S<Subset2, Subset3>> // error!
// -----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '10' is not assignable to type '1'.


On the other hand, if you're going to do this sort of thing often, you might want to write a reusable helper function or class or type that partitions a union into exhaustive and exclusive tuple types.  Again, lots of ways to approach it:
class Partition<const T, U extends (readonly any[])[] = []> {
    constructor(public members: T[], public u: U = [] as any as U) { }
    sub<const V extends readonly T[]>(v: V): Partition<Exclude<T, V[number]>, [...U, V]> {
        return new Partition(this.members as any, [...this.u, v])
    }
    end(this: Partition<never, U>): U {
        return this.u;
    }
}

const [subset1, subset2, subset3] =
    new Partition([1, 2, 3, 4]).sub([1]).sub([2, 3]).sub([4]).end();

Now you pass in the original array to new Partition and then you can call sub() until you run out of elements, and finally call end() to get the subsets out. If you re-use elements, or call end() too early, you'll get errors:
const [subset1, subset2, subset3] =
    new Partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).sub([1]).sub([2, 3]).sub([4]).end(); // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  The 'this' context of type 'Partition<5, [readonly [1], readonly [2, 3], readonly [4]]>' 
//  is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 
//  'Partition<never, [readonly [1], readonly [2, 3], readonly [4]]>'.

Playground link to code
